# Visual Studio: Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type 'DOMDocument'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

Recently I've been unable to build my project at work because of the following error:

> Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type
>   'DOMDocument'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

To be honest I'm not really sure how to approach the error, nor can I fiqure out what's wrong. It's giving me the file that is the cause, that has these import statements at the top:

```
Imports X.Online.Core
Imports X.Online.Connectivity
Imports X.Online.Classes
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web
Imports X.Asp.Classes
Imports X.Asp.Core
Imports X.Asp.SiteSpecific
Imports MSXML2
Imports X.Online.State
Imports Elmah
```

From what I can gather, it seems to be that I'm missing something, and I've had a look and at first I thought it was a missing MSXML2, but it appears in my references as "Interop.MSXML2" so now I'm not sure that's the problem. I should add that this problem appeared after upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 7.

I've also read the advice listed here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2010/06/11/troubleshooting-errors-when-embedding-type-information-doug-rothaus/

And I've also tried repairing my .net 4 installation.

I would be very grateful if someone could offer some advice as to how I can go about fixing this error!

Comment: MSXML2 is a COM type library.  The interop library for it will be automatically embedded thanks to the "Embed Interop Types" assembly property so you don't need the Interop.MSXML2.dll file at runtime.  You will get this error if it is embedded in one project but not in another.  Review the assembly references in your projects and make sure the property is the consistently set to True.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I was right in thinking that DOMDocument is referring to the MSXML2 import?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply. I've checked in the projects, and in one it's listed as "Microsoft XML, v6.0" and in the other project it's listed as "Interop.MSXML2". Could this be the cause of the problem? They're both set to "True".

Answer (score 6):

Just to let people know, if anyone else ever has a similar problem. It seemed that my problem was that Visual Studio had imported the Interop file for the two projects, but both projects linked to a separate version of the .dll. I removed them both and made sure to add a reference to the exact same file and this solved my problem.